# check box is not working in edit page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

The select all check box is working well at the initial time. 
steps:
1.Consider I check some check boxes or check all check box , then saving the form 
2.Editing the saved form shows nothing checked. It shows the check box as in initial stage. Nothing saved.

Javascript

```
<%= check_box_tag "box_select_all" %>

<%= check_box_tag "box_id[]", box.id, false, class: 'box_select' %>
```

jQuery

```
$('body').delegate('#box_select_all', 'click', function() {
  $('.box_select').prop('checked', this.checked);
});


$('body').delegate('.box_select', 'click', function() {
  if ($(".box_select").length == $(".box_select:checked").length) {
    $("#box_select_all").prop("checked", "checked");
  } else {
  $("#box_select_all").prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

Can anybody help me??

Comment: is this a type-o? "$('.box_select').prop('checked', this.checked);ox"

Comment: @ajt- ya.sorry. will change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to delegate that function on body, when you will click the checkbox, function will be called. Call it like this:

```
$("#box_select_all").click(function() {
  $(".box_select").prop('checked', this.checked);
});

$(".box_select").click(function() {
  if ($(".box_select").length == $(".box_select:checked").length) {
    $("#box_select_all").prop("checked", "checked");
  } 
  else {
  $("#box_select_all").prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#select_all").click(function){
   $(".select_class").attr("checked",true);

});
```

That means you just add same class to all your checkboxes and do this code on your select box all checkbox, on its onclick function. gud luck